# Pixel Shader Constant Buffer alignment

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I have a pixel shader buffer

```
cbuffer InputBuffer {
   float fTextureWidth;
   float fTextureHeight;
   float fTimeStep;
   float padding;   //padding to align to 16 bytes
};
```

That corresponds to a struct in my shader class:

```
struct InputBuffer {
    float fTextureWidth;
    float fTextureHeight;
    float fTimeStep;
    float padding;
};
```

Which looks all fine, since its 16-byte aligned. But when I render I get this warning:

The size of the Constant Buffer at slot 0 of the Pixel Shader unit is too small (16 bytes provided, 32 bytes, at least, expected). This is OK, as out-of-bounds reads are defined to return 0. It is also possible the developer knows the missing data will not be used anyway. This is only a problem if the developer actually intended to bind a sufficiently large Constant Buffer for what the shader expects.  [ EXECUTION WARNING #351: DEVICE_DRAW_CONSTANT_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL]

Why would the buffer expect 32 bytes? I thought 16 was the minimum and mine clearly is?

**EDIT 1:** I've added the output of D3DReflect and my shader code.
After running D3DReflect on the pixel shader and retrieving a ID3D11ShaderReflectionConstantBuffer pointer to the constant buffer I ran the GetDesc method on the buffer and got what I expected: 
     Type: D3D_CT_BUFFER(0)
     Variables: 4
     Size: 16
     Flags: 0

As requested, here is the pixel shader code:

```
/////////////
// GLOBALS //
/////////////
Texture2D shaderTextures[2];    // 0 is the velocity field texture and 1 is the field that is to be advected
SamplerState SampleType;

/////////////
// BUFFERS //
/////////////
cbuffer InputBuffer {
    float fTextureWidth;
    float fTextureHeight;
    float fTimeStep;
    float fDissipation;
};


//////////////
// TYPEDEFS //
//////////////
struct PixelInputType {
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

// Pixel Shader
float4 AdvectionPixelShader(PixelInputType input) : SV_TARGET {
    float2 u = shaderTextures[0].Sample(SampleType, input.tex).xy;  // velocity

    float2 rdFactors = float2(1.0f/fTextureWidth,1.0f/fTextureHeight);

    float2 prevPos = float2(input.tex.x - (fTimeStep*rdFactors.x*u.x),input.tex.y - (fTimeStep*rdFactors.y*u.y) );

    float2 final = shaderTextures[1].Sample(SampleType,prevPos).xy;

    return float4(final,0.0f,1.0f)*fDissipation;
}
```

Comment: That's interesting, did you try to run D3DReflect on your shader to query the cbuffer size? If possible could you also post the whole shader code too? (or a simplified version which generates the same warning)

Comment: Hi - I have edited my post adding the things you asked for.

Comment: could you show also how you create the buffer on  the CPU side?